# swiperjs to set automatically the number of sildes per view

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, swiper.js

I am creating a photo carousel using swiperJS [ref link here](http://idangero.us/swiper/).

Here are the params of the swiper:

```
mySwiper = Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: false,
    speed: 800,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    grabCursor: true,
    spaceBetween: 2,
    initialSlide: 0,
    keyboardControl: false,
    resizeReInit: true,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: false,
    nextButton: '.swiper-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-prev'
});
```

My purpose is to fit as many slides into the view as possible. The photos are of different width and size, some are landscape mode and some are portrait.

**Problem:** only showing one slide per view.

**Goal**: fit in as many slides as possible into view.

could somebody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 31):

Swiper slides are set by default to 100% width in swiper.css:

```
.swiper-slide {
  ...
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

When you initialize swiper with `slidesPerView: 'auto'`, it will not explicitly set the width sizes of the slides to a calculated number (like it would if you define the slides per view to a fixed number) but it will use the existing slide widths. Without any css/inline style changes, these widths will be 100%.

Note that in the [example](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/140-centered-auto.html) on the swiper website for `slidesPerView: 'auto'` you can see how they explicitly set the widths of the slides they want to have a different width in css:

```
.swiper-slide:nth-child(2n) {
      width: 40%;
    }
.swiper-slide:nth-child(3n) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

So if you want to use the original image widths just set the swiper slide widths to auto:

```
.swiper-slide {
    width: auto;
}
```

Code snippet to show how it works:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      centeredSlides: true,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* this is the important part */
.swiper-container .swiper-slide {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.5/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">how about</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">fitting some text</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">also</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In 2022 this problem still persist. I lost so much time trying to figure this out, why this is not default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: false,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    freeMode: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    initialSlide: 3, //optional
    slidesPerGroup: 2, // if set, it helps it to align in the left if set to 1
});
```